# How do i make this (logic) portion of a C++ hospital management program?

Tags: c++

I'm looking for help in understanding what logic has to be used here.

I have to display names of some cities to a user. Then the user can select a city. From the selected city, names of particular doctors belonging to that city have to be displayed, from which the user can choose a doctor.

I have tried to make a txt file, and import the data into the program. But in this way, it's not possible to first output the city names, and then choose a doctor from that city.

I have also tried to use a structure, but the same problem, as i'm unable to print only city names first, and then the doctors of that city.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question, and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site.

Comment: Your question is too broad.  If you have no idea where to begin, then you are tackling a problem that is beyond your current skillset and with potentially too big a learning curve.  Start with smaller problems, and build up your experience, after which point you will have a better idea of how to approach the task.  As currently written, there are gaping holes in your description of the program's requirements.  This illustrates a poor grasp of the problem itself.  I recommend you break it down into smaller chunks and look at each one separately.

Comment: Thank you sukhi and paddy. I'm trying to make a college project. I've made a lot of it. But i'm stuck on this portion. And i'm  not asking people to write the code for me. I only want to know what logic has to be used here so that i can code it

Comment: In that case, rather than try to describe the whole program and ask for help with no code, you should instead create a question about one specific thing and show your code related to that.  Be as clear and concise as you can about the problem you are facing, and you may get some useful answers.

Comment: okay, i've changed the question to try to be more accurate in describing my problem

Comment: No, that doesn't help.  This question is doomed anyway.  As I say, ask a question about a specific thing and _support that question with example code_.  We do not want to see just words and vague descriptions.  We want code, or we have no idea what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: If it were me, I would read the text file that has rows of city,doctor and would put the data into a `std::map<std::string,std::vector<std::string>>` where the key of the map is the city name and the vector holds the names of the doctors in that city.  Then if you enumerate the keys of the maps you get the names of the cities and if you lookup the name of a city you get a vector of doctors names.  Maybe I should make an answer...

Comment: Paddy's advice to start small and learn can actually be used while developing this program. Most of the time a big problem is a whole bunch of little problems ganging up on you. Isolate the little problems that you do know how to solve and use them as practice AND the building blocks for solving the problems you don't yet know how to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't been clear about what your text file looks like so I am assuming it is comma separated and contains two columns: `city,doctor`

We don't want to read comma separated items from the file because then if a line has only a city or a doctor but not both we will lose track of which one we are reading.  So instead we should read whole lines from the file and split them up into city and doctor afterward.  That way we can ignore lines that don't have both a city and a doctor.

Then you have to read the file.  If you use a map that uses city as the key and a vector of doctors as the value then you can enumerate the keys or enumerate one of the vectors after you know the city: `std::map<std::string,std::vector<std::string> > city_doctor_map;`

Here is a link to a working sample including an input file: https://onlinegdb.com/H1N0gFTZr

And here is the code I came up with:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // first open the file
    std::ifstream fin("untitled.txt");

    // then read lines from the file
    std::string str;
    std::map<std::string,std::vector<std::string> > city_doctor_map;
    while(getline(fin,str))
    {
        // and for each line put it in a string stream so we can split it up afterwards
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << str;

        // we could just read comma separated bits directly from the file with
        // while(getline(fin,str,',')) { ... }
        // but then if one of the lines doesn't have both halves we get messed up
        // so it is better if we read one line at a time and split that up afterward

        // then read comma separated bits from the string stream
        std::string city,doctor;
        if(getline(ss,city,',') && getline(ss,doctor,','))
        {
            // if we don't have both bits then don't do anything
            if (city.length()>0 && doctor.length()>0)
            {
                // if we do have both bits then get the vector of doctors from the map
                // (creating it if necessary) and add the doctor to it
                std::vector<std::string> &doctors = city_doctor_map[city];
                doctors.push_back(doctor);
                std::cout << "added " << doctor << " to " << city << "\n";
            }
        }
    }

    // now print the keys of the map
    std::cout << "\ncities:\n";
    for ( const auto &item : city_doctor_map ) {
        std::cout << item.first << "\n";
    }

    // you could read this from the user input...
    std::string city = "city4";

    // now print the doctors in the city
    std::cout << "\ndoctors in " << city << ":\n";
    for ( const auto &item : city_doctor_map[city] ) {
        std::cout << item << "\n";
    }

    // all done
    return 0;
}
```